# Debugger for Protractor in WebStorm IDE

Tags: debugging, protractor, webstorm, nightwatch.js

I want to know how I can setup debugger for Protractor test automation in WebStorm IDE. I have done it for Nightwatch framework but not sure about Protractor.

Answer (score 0):

You can run/debug your protractor tests using [Protractor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/run-debug-configuration-protractor.html) run configuration. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/protractor.html, https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/10/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-6957/ for more info

Comment: That Helps, Thanks a lot.